# Myriad bad behavior from matplotlib under python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

When attempting to draw a figure with matplotlib under python3, calls to pyplot.show() fail to do anything.

(script bonker.py)

```
import matplotlib
import numpy as np

print('Matplotlib version '+matplotlib.__version__) ; 
print('Matplotlib is using '+matplotlib.backends.backend) ; 
print('Numpy version '+np.__version__) ; 

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

infile=open('/usr/share/dict/words') ; 
vals=list() ; 
for line in infile : 
    vals += [ len(line.strip()) ] ; 
print('Values collected. ('+repr(len(vals))+' items.)') ; 

(hist,bin_edges)=np.histogram(vals,bins=20) ; 

myf=plt.figure() ; 
mya=myf.add_subplot(111) ;
mya.bar(bin_edges[1:],hist) ; 
plt.ion() ; 
print('plt.interactive is '+repr(plt.isinteractive())) ;
plt.show() ;
```

(execution in ipython)

```
I1> %run bonker.py
Matplotlib version 1.5.0
Matplotlib is using GTK3Agg
Numpy version 1.10.1
Values collected. (479828 items.)
plt.interactive is True

I2>
```

Then, nothing happens. `plt.show()` does nothing even after repeated calls.
HOWEVER, if I try to explicitly show the figure (`plt.show(myf)`), then the figure displays properly, but the shell is no longer responsive and remains unresponsive even after the figure is closed. Does anybody know what I can do (hopefully short of rebuilding python3 and matplotlib) to fix these behaviors?

Comment: try running `%matplotlib` in ipython before running your script

Comment: %matplotlib makes it work-- any idea how? And how I can I implement this so that people could use it in normal python3 (i.e. not i python)